BrowserStack errors running IPA
I'm testing an IPA created with React Native with the aim of testing it on different iPhones. The app seems to work apparently well without any strange behavior, but when I'm running the app on BrowserStack I can see a lot of "errors" or "warnings" in the console:
Jun  6 13:15:49 SpringBoard(XCTAutomationSupport)[34] <Error>: Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.
Jun  6 13:15:49 sharingd[68] <Error>: SDAirDropNearFieldService: missing Near field Controller, will not start polling
Jun  6 13:15:49 SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter)[34] <Error>: Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 0; sceneIdentity: (null)
Jun  6 13:15:49 mobile_storage_proxy(Network)[250] <Error>: nw_read_request_report [C1042] Receive failed with error "Connection reset by peer"
Jun  6 13:15:49 mobile_storage_proxy(Network)[250] <Error>: nw_read_request_report [C1043] Receive failed with error "Connection reset by peer"
Jun  6 13:15:49 CFNetworkAgent(libboringssl.dylib)[2760] <Error>: boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(44) [C3.1.1.1:2][0x59e141000] Error: 4313006560:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.cc:231:
Jun  6 13:15:54 duetexpertd(AppPredictionInternal)[199] <Error>: No poi category received from biome stream, so returning default poi category
Jun  6 13:15:59 wifid(WiFiPolicy)[50] <Error>: WiFiManagerHelperInsertWiFiServiceToNetworkSetsIfNotPresent: FOUND network service A5E32044-9382-4FAD-95D9-798495461CB9 with matching BSD name en0 and interface type IEEE80211
Jun  6 13:15:59 mobile_storage_proxy(Network)[250] <Error>: nw_socket_handle_socket_event <private> Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]

Are that warnings "normal" or not when we run an IPA on BrowserStack? I'm pretty new to BrowserStack. The app doesn't crash, and when I google the "errors" I wasn't able to find a clear answer of why they appeared.
I tried to find if that "errors" appear when I run the app on my XCode iOS simulator, but in general the "errors" don't appear on XCode console.

Any luck with this issue ?

Hi @Fawaz, unfortunately I haven't been able to find an answer to this. The app apparently works fine, I'm not sure what mean that warnings in BrowserStack.
